# Have QnA maker respond to a Yes or No question

Tags: boolean, response, azure-qna-maker

I would like to answer a Yes or No question to enable my bot/QnA knowledge base circle back to a specific question in the conversation.

For example:

```
User: I need help.
QnA: How can I help?
User: I am after information on Arterial Lines
QnA: The QRG written on "Arterial Lines, Venous Sheaths and Insertion Site
     Management" might be useful.
QnA: Was this QRG helpful? Choose Yes or No
User: No
QnA: How can I help?
```

That's what I am going for.  Trying to do this no code for now.  Would appreciate support on navigating the qnamaker.ai interface.

I have tried in context responses, but can't work out how to prompt the user for a pathway or either Yes or No.

Comment: When you say 'no code', do you mean there is no bot? just clicking through the qna interface?

Answer (score 1):

QnA Maker has (in preview as of this answer) a 'follow-up prompt' functionality. It allows you to connect one question to another in a sort of water fall.

[image: Image of QnA Maker with questions chained together]

You'll have to play around to get the format you want, but you can chain the 'yes/no' question back to the initial prompt question easily enough.

I know you said you're going no code, by the way, but I would recommend looking into LUIS anyway. QnA Maker is for very specific questions with exactish wording. Any major deviations in how your users interact with your bot and it's not going to perform how you expect.